# Are limit point and subsequential limit of a sequence in a metric space equivalent?

Tags: general-topology

```
I have little doubts on the equivalence of the definitions of limit point and subsequential limit of a sequence in a metric space.

To avoid ambiguities, the definitions of the above terms are as follows:
```

Given a metric space ($X, d$) with metric $d$, let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$.

(i) $p$ is a limit point of $\{x_n\}$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_N \neq p$ and $d(x_N, p) < \epsilon$.

(ii) $q$ is a subsequential limit of $\{x_n\}$ if there exists a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ converges to $q$.

Are they equivalent definitions? Though I think they are equivalent, there is a counterexample of this claim :

Consider $\{(-1)^n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with standard metric. -1 is a subsequential limit but not a limit point of the sequence.

Comment: I do believe the definition of a limit point that you've listed is wrong; it should be that $p$ is a limit point of $\{x_n\}$ iff $\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq N, 0<d(x_n, p)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: @SamuelLijin No, this is a strengthening of a limit, not a limit point, which is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counterexample is correct. The crux is the $x_N \neq p$ condition in being a limit point.

It is true that if $p$ is a limit point of the sequence, it is a subsequential limit of that sequence, at least in metric spaces (and first countable spaces more generally).

Also if $q$ is a subsequential  limit of the sequence with infinitely many different terms then $q$ is a limit point of the sequence.

So the notions are closely related but not quite equivalent.

Comment: That means whether $\{x_n\}$ as a set is finite or not distinguishes these two definitions in metric space. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even if there are infinitely many points, like the sequence $1,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{3},1,\frac{1}{4},1,\ldots$ there can be subsequential a subsequential limit ($1$) that is not a limit point of the sequence. This is because even when there are infinitely many terms, there can be lots of constant subsequences...